# What happens to you if you use code from StackOverflow but it turns out to be copyright protected?

Tags: copyright, licensing

Code posted on StackOverflow is under a [CC license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) but if someone were to post proprietary, copyrighted code that you use in your own project unknowingly, could the copyright holder come after you with a cease-and-desist order? What would be your options at that point?

Comment: All code, essentially, is copyrighted. Not all is proprietary. You re talking about someone who posts code to SO without having the right to release it under the CC license, correct?

Comment: @DavidSiegel well the author of the first computer program died in 1852, so that is in the public domain.

Comment: @phoog  True. But as a practical matter, all code current enough to be of ay use is under copyright. I was mostly reacting to those who use "copyrighted" as another word for "proprietary" or "closed source".

Comment: @DavidSiegel Which is perhaps more of a trade secret issue than copyright.

Answer (score 4):

In general, using content provided by another who incorrectly posted it under a permissive license, such as a CC license, does not grant a valid license from the real copyright holder.

That is, if A writes some code (or a song, or creates an image, or whatever else), it is protected by copyright. If B then posts it to the web, with a statement that it is released under a particular license, without having obtained permission from A, then B's "release" is of no value, because B had no rights to grant. If C downloads and uses this content, relying on B's license, then A could take legal action against C. C would probably be considered (in the US) an "innocent infringer" which reduces the minimum statutory damage amount, but does not otherwise change C's legal position. A could, if it chose, bring suit and possibly obtain a judgement including some damages.

But to return to the practical case of code posted on one of the SE sites. Given the comparatively short code sections usually posted, and that they do not usually form a complete working program, and given further the stated educational purpose of SE, it is likely that in US law such a posting would constitute ***fair use***, and in the law of other countries fall under one or another ***exception to copyright***. That is a general conclusion, the details would matter.

I have not heard of a case similar to that suggested in the question. I find it unlikely that an SE poster would post copyright-protected code without permission, that is valuable enough to be worth an infringement suit, and substantial enough and having enough effect on th market for the original to be outside the protection of fair use. Such a situatiion is, of course, possible, even if unlikely.

Note that a cease-and-desist letter is not a court order, and is really only a threat of court action. its only **legal** effect is to put the recipient on notice, so that continued infringement is not without awareness of the copyright claim.  To have legal effect the claimant must actually bring an infringement suit, which is not without cost.

Comment: Just because SE use is fair use, doesn’t mean a subsequent user’s is.

Comment: @Dale M. Quite true, But given the relatively small size of most SE/SO code posts, compared to any useful program or app, I think most are likely to constitute fair use for any subsequent user. Obviously;y there is no way to be sure of that without the details of the code and the way in which a re-user might make use of it. I will clarify that in my answer latter this evening.

Comment: It's not likely to get really bad with code posted on stack exchange. But code owned by my employer that I post on GitHub under a GPL license without any right to do so could be much worse.

Comment: @gnasher729 which leads to the inevitable question, why are you doing that?

Comment: @phoog Well, I wouldn't. With fear of legal consequences being one of a long list of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

SE code is not Fair Use despite what the comment to another answer says. It's [Creative Commons "Data Dump"](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) which makes a pretty huge difference.

Comment: -1 The creative commons license is very cler that it only licenses what is protected byb copyright. This means that if a use is fair use, and therefore not infringement, it is not covered under any CC license, and the CC terms need not be complied with. Also, the qestion asks, or seems to ask, about co0de posted to SE by someone who does not  have the right to release it under a CC license, so the license would not apply at all.

Comment: @DavidSiegel if you post something that's in the public domain, that's not fair use; it's public domain.  If you post something that's not in the public domain, but your posting it doesn't infringe copyright because it's fair use, the material is still protected by copyright.  I don't know which CC term you're referring to, but it can't convert protected material into public domain material simply because someone once made fair use of it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think there being no copyright means there can't be fair use. If something goes to court, and the copyright situation is unclear and complicated, a judge would be able to say "no matter if there is copyright or not, it was fair use, so the case is closed".

Comment: @phoog I was reacting to a cmt saying something isn't fair use because it is under a CC license.  The CC text is careful to release only those rights protected by copyright, authorizing acts which would be infringement if not authorized. But if a **particular** use is a fair use, it is not infringement, and thus is not covered by the CC lic, then the CC terms don't apply, and neither does ther SA obligation. That does **not** mean the work is PD, only that** this use** is a faire use, and so not under the CC lic.

Comment: @gnasher729  Sorry it doesn't work like that. The **first** issue, as I understand it, is always "is there a valid copyright?" Only if the answer is "yes" is the matter of fair use gone into. Fair use is an **exception to copyright**. It does not apply if there is no copyright. Just as one can't get a divorce from a person if there is no marriage to start with.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I see. Anyway if the CC license purported to grant permission to, e.g., quote a short passage for the purpose of a review, it would have no effect other than to make the drafters of the license look like they didn't know what they were doing.  But in response to your comment to gnasher729 I would note that courts often bypass an issue if the case can be decided on a different question.  If the defendant argues that no copyright existed or alternatively that if there is copyright then it's fair use, the judge can avoid determining whether copyright existed by ruling (slightly...

Comment: ...differently from @gnasher729's wording) "if there was copyright then this was fair use, so the claim fails."  This only applies, though, if the outcome in the case is the same for a finding of "no copyright" and a finding of "copyright but fair use."

Comment: @phoog Yes, in many cases, courts do bypass some issuers to look for the easiest issue that will determine the case. Perhaps that is done in copyright cases too. But in every copyright case where  I have read an opinion, the issue of whether there is a valid copyright is addressed **before** the isue of fair use is even addressed.